# How to extract file from zip without maintaining directory structure in Python?

Tags: python, zip, unzip, directory-structure

I'm trying to extract a specific file from a zip archive using python.

In this case, extract an apk's icon from the apk itself.

I am currently using

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/my_file.apk') as z:
    # extract /res/drawable/icon.png from apk to /temp/...
    z.extract('/res/drawable/icon.png', 'temp/')
```

which does work, in my script directory it's creating `temp/res/drawable/icon.png` which is temp plus the same path as the file is inside the apk.

What I actually want is to end up with `temp/icon.png`.

Is there any way of doing this directly with a zip command, or do I need to extract, then move the file, then remove the directories manually?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use [zipfile.ZipFile.open](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open):

```
import shutil
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/my_file.apk') as z:
    with z.open('/res/drawable/icon.png') as zf, open('temp/icon.png', 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(zf, f)
```

Or use [zipfile.ZipFile.read](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.read):

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/my_file.apk') as z:
    with open('temp/icon.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(z.read('/res/drawable/icon.png'))
```

Comment: Both very nice answers, far more eloquent than just moving it like I was. Minor correction to fit question asked, is with open(os.path.join(tDir,os.path.basename(icon[1])), 'wb') as f:  so that the output icon is in the temp dir, not cwd() where script is. Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that the CPython implementations of `extract` and `extract_all` use the "`zipfile.ZipFile.open`" version: e.g. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Lib/zipfile.py#L1647

Comment: You're welcome @falsetru . I tried your implementation and I noticed some problems, that I realized that was the lack of the import. Besides this, it works like a clockwork.

Comment: Be aware that using `zipfile.ZipFile.read` will load the full file in memory before writing it to the disk.