# AWS Lambda to get file from ZIP on S3 without download

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a zip file on S3 and I need to get a single file from the zip.
I would like to avoid downloading the whole ZIP, I don't know what size the ZIP may have and I only need a small file from that ZIP.
I want to do this with a Lambda function (it can be nodejs or python).

Comment: are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729703/how-to-extract-file-from-zip-without-maintaining-directory-structure-in-python?

Comment: Hmm, could be, but not sure if it works with the ZIP being on S3.

Comment: You might be able to use [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/), which knows how to talk to S3 and understands zip files.